# Matching one column of data with two other different columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

Hi i have three columns

```
ColumnA   COLUMN H   COLUMN G
```

I have to write an excel formula in fourth column where it will search for matching values from `Column A` in `Column H` and `COLUMN G` . Like if the value in `Column A` be present in any one column of A or B it should be Yes otherwise if it is not present then it is no

Here what i have tried but not working

```
= IF(OR(MATCH(A2, $H:$H | $G:$G ,0)),"Yes","No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very poor quality question. Try below formula.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,G:G,0),MATCH(A1,H:H,0))),"Yes","No")
```

[image]